# problems in outbound calls in asterisk

Tags: voip, asterisk, telephony, sip-server

i am having problem in making calls

i have vicidial CE 1.1

i am having following errors

```
   -- Remote UNIX connection
-- Executing AGI("SIP/sou101-0996c9e0", "agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log") in new stack
-- AGI Script agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log completed, returning 0
-- Executing Dial("SIP/sou101-0996c9e0", "sip/12127773456@netmax|55|o") in new stack
-- Called 12127773456@netmax
Mar  4 14:23:46 NOTICE[2312]: chan_sip.c:2040 auto_congest: Auto-congesting SIP/netmax-  0997de68
-- SIP/netmax-0997de68 is circuit-busy
 == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/1/0)
-- Executing Hangup("SIP/sou101-0996c9e0", "") in new stack
== Spawn extension (default, 912127773456, 3) exited non-zero on 'SIP/sou101-0996c9e0'
-- Executing DeadAGI("SIP/sou101-0996c9e0", "agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log") in new  stack
-- AGI Script agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log completed, returning 0
-- Executing DeadAGI("SIP/sou101-0996c9e0", "agi://127.0.0.1:4577/VD_hangup--HVcauses--  PRI-----NODEBUG-----16-----CONGESTION----------)") in new stack
-- AGI Script agi://127.0.0.1:4577/VD_hangup--HVcauses--PRI-----NODEBUG-----16-----  CONGESTION----------) completed, returning 0
```

and such problems...

```
  == Manager 'sendcron' logged off from 127.0.0.1
-- Executing AGI("SIP/sou101-099366c8", "agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log") in new stack
-- AGI Script agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log completed, returning 0
-- Executing Dial("SIP/sou101-099366c8", "sip/12127773456@voip|55|o") in new stack
-- Called 12127773456@voip
 Mar  4 14:24:10 WARNING[2312]: chan_sip.c:9894 handle_response_invite: Forbidden - wrong  password on authentication for INVITE to '"sou101" <sip:20011@64.79.82.245>;tag=as532e4da7'
-- SIP/voip-09969dc0 is circuit-busy
== Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/1/0)
-- Executing Hangup("SIP/sou101-099366c8", "") in new stack
== Spawn extension (default, 812127773456, 3) exited non-zero on 'SIP/sou101-099366c8'
-- Executing DeadAGI("SIP/sou101-099366c8", "agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log") in new  stack
-- AGI Script agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log completed, returning 0
-- Executing DeadAGI("SIP/sou101-099366c8", "agi://127.0.0.1:4577/VD_hangup--HVcauses-- PRI-----NODEBUG-----21-----CONGESTION----------)") in new stack
-- AGI Script agi://127.0.0.1:4577/VD_hangup--HVcauses--PRI-----NODEBUG-----21-----CONGESTION----------) completed, returning 0
```

I see this  ***WARNING[4638]: chan_sip.c:9894 handle_response_invite: Forbidden - wrong password on authentication for INVITE to '"adm201" ;tag=as0913dc74'***

I am not finding any way out.. 
please help

Answer (score 0):

Very likly you have incorrect setup of trunk. To got more info, you can consider do

```
asterisk -r
sip set debug peer voip
```